# How can Iset WebGL camera aspect ratio to canvas (window) aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, webgl

I've made my webGL content fill the browser window using:

css:

```
canvas
  {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

And also:

```
function webGLStart() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("cool3D");
    canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    ...
```

So far, this is effective for maintaining full coverage, no matterthe size of the window or fullscreen. The problem is assigning the aspect ratio of the camera to avoid distortion.

How can I set it to ~"window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight"? OnWindowResize?

Comment: Well, just call gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) and create another projection matrix with the new aspect ratio (canvas.width / canvas.height) on the event, pass it to your shader uniform.

Comment: I tried that, but it seems like Firefox doesn't treat odd aspect ratios consistently. Will take another look tonight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the viewport. It's actually a function of the perspective matrix. Your code will vary, but in my own every time I detect that the window is resized I do the following:

```
mat4.perspective(45.0, canvas.width/canvas.height, znear, zfar, projectionMat);
```

Which updates my projection matrix to use the appropriate aspect ratio (width/height).